# No. of enteries/rows not getting updated for ajax call in bootstrap data table

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I working on a `CodeIgniter` project where I'm using bootstrap data tables to display all users(active/inactive).

I've got a select box, through which I can switch between active and inactive users and an ajax call handles all these requirements. When I switch, an `ajax` call renders the row without any issue. But the no of entries or rows are not updated. Below are code snippets.
Here is my HTML

```
<section class="content">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-header">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/user/add_user" title="Add User">Add User</a>
                    <div class="form-group pull-right form-group-bottom" style="margin-right: 1%;">
                        <label class="col-md-4 user-action-label">Action </label>
                        <div class="col-md-8" style="padding-left: 0px !important;">
                            <select class="form-control" id="user-action">
                                <option value="1">Active</option>
                                <option value="0">Inactive</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="box-title">All Users</h3>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-header -->
                <div class="box-body">
                  <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Slno.</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="user_table">
                        <?php if($result) { $i =1; foreach ($result as $row){ ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row->fullname; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row->username; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row->email; ?></td>
                            <td><?php if($row->active == "1"){ ?>
                                <span class="label label-success"><?php echo 'Active'; ?></span>  
                            <?php }elseif($row->active == "0"){ ?>
                                <span class="label label-warning"><?php echo 'Inactive'; ?></span>
                            <?php } ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-success" href="<?php echo base_url().'admin/user/view_user?id='.$row->user_id.'&action=edit'; ?>" title="View">
                                      <i class="ace-icon fa fa-pencil-square-o bigger-120"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php  $i++; } } ?>
                    </tbody>
                    <p id="no_data" style="font-weight: bold;"></p>
                  </table>

                </div>
                <!-- /.box-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.box -->
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here is my JS

(I've ajax `complete` function. Still not working)

```
$(function() {

$("#user-action").change(function (){
   $user_action = $("#user-action").val();

   $.ajax({
        url: base_url+"admin/user/user_action",
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: {
            'value':$user_action
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if(data != "false"){
                $("#user_table").html(data);
                $("#no_data").html("");
            }else if(data == "false"){
                $("#user_table").html("");
                $("#no_data").html("No Inactive Users");
            }
        }
   });
});
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){        
    $(document).find("#example1").DataTable();
});
```

Here is my controller

```
public function user_action(){
    if(trim($this->input->post('value')) != NULL){
        $status = trim($this->input->post('value'));

        $data = array('active' => $status,
                      'usertype !=' => 'Admin'
                    );
        $is_avail = $this->user_model->get_records('user_table',$data);
        if($is_avail){

            $output = "";
            $i = 1;
            foreach ($is_avail as $row){
                if($row->active == "1"){
                    $action_span = "<span class='label label-success'>Active</span>";  
                }elseif($row->active == "0"){
                    $action_span = "<span class='label label-warning'>Inactive</span>";
                }
                $output .= '<tr>
                                <td>'. $i.'</td>
                                <td>'.$row->fullname.'</td>
                                <td>'.$row->username.'</td>
                                <td>'.$row->email.'</td>
                                <td>'.$action_span.'</td>
                                <td>
                                  <div class="btn-group">
                                      <a class="btn btn-xs btn-success" href='. base_url().'admin/user/view_user?id='.$row->user_id.'&action=edit title="View">
                                        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-pencil-square-o bigger-120"></i>
                                      </a>
                                  </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>';
                $i++;
            }
            if($output != ""){
                echo $output;
            }else{
                echo 'false';
            }

        }else{
            echo 'false';
        }
    }else{
        echo 'false';
    }
}
```

Here is my snapshot: active users(Onload - working normally)
[image]

inactive users (No users - No of entries are not updated)
[image]

inactive users(User exist - No of entries are not updated)
[image]

Please help me out.

[image]

Comment: what does the ajax calls show in the network tab ?

Comment: The response has no issues. I'm getting what I need. A string with <tr><td> The only problem is in showing the data.

Comment: @muhammad Omar Aslam, Please refer snap in the question.

Comment: yeah i just saw it, that means the response is received then in the `success` function where you are adding the html inside `if(data != "false"){` condition can you verify there is only a single element with the id `#user_table` try `$("#user_table").length` and after receiving the response type in console `$("#user_table").html()` does it show you something.

Comment: $("#user_table").length is giving me 1(One)

Comment: what about the `$("#user_table").html()` after receiving the response does it prints the desired html columns that should be received from the response

Comment: Yep, that is what is being shown in the 3rd snapshot. Tried displaying multiple rows. That is also working. It is because, I'm reinitializing the data table in the ajaxcomplete.

Comment: maybe I am wrong but the documentation says to update the datatable rows in somewhat different way, `var table = $('#example').DataTable(); table.rows.add( [ { "name": "Tiger Nixon", "position": "System Architect", "salary": "$3,120", "start_date": "2011/04/25", "office": "Edinburgh", "extn": "5421" } ] ) .draw()`

Comment: You are saying that I should append the full json to the table.row.add function?? I referred the documentation. Is there any other way to achieve this??

Comment: yeah the documentation here https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add() states that you should use the api function to add rows to the table and the `.draw()` to populate them after updating or adding see here https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw() , you should also look at `clear()` you may need that too for clearing the table https://datatables.net/reference/api/clear()

Comment: That's cool. Will try to include it in my stuff. Let's see if that can solve my problem. Anyhow thanks, mate.

Comment: no problem, we all here are a community, and we should help out each other. Be good.